# Define dtypes in NumPy using a list?

Tags: python, numpy

I just am having a problem with NumPy dtypes. Essentially I'm trying to create a table that looks like the following (and then save it using rec2csv):

```
      name1   name2   name3 . . . 
name1  #       #      #
name2  #       #      #
name2  #       #      #
.
.
.
```

The matrix (numerical array in the center), is already computed before I attempt to add the name tags. I've tried to use the following code:

```
    dt = dtype({'names' : tuple(blah), 'formats' : tuple(fmt)}) 
    ReadArray = array(tuplelist, dtype=dt)
```

where tuplelist is a list of rows (i.e. the row [name1, #, #, #...]), blah is a list of strings (i.e. the names, `blah = ['name1', 'name2', ...]`) and fmt is the list of format,s (i.e. `fmt = [str, float, float, ...]`).

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "table_calc_try2.py", line 152, in table_calc_try2
    dt = dtype({'names' : tuple(blah), 'formats' : tuple(fmt)}) 
TypeError: data type not understood
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

The following code might help:

```
import numpy as np

dt = np.dtype([('name1', '|S10'), ('name2', '<f8')])
tuplelist=[
    ('n1', 1.2),
    ('n2', 3.4),    
     ]
arr = np.array(tuplelist, dtype=dt)

print(arr['name1'])
# ['n1' 'n2']
print(arr['name2'])
# [ 1.2  3.4]
```

Your immediate problem was that `np.dtype` expects the format specifiers to be numpy types, such as `'|S10'` or `'<f8'` and not Python types, such as `str` or `float`.  If you type `help(np.dtype)` you'll see many examples of how `np.dtypes` can be specified. (I've only mentioned a few.)

Note that np.array expects a list of tuples. It's rather particular about that.

A list of lists raises `TypeError: expected a readable buffer object`.

A (tuple of tuples) or a (tuple of lists) raises `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`.

Comment: Just as a note: a dict of the form the OP gave is a perfectly valid dtype (other than not specifying numpy types, as you mentioned (e.g. np.float rather than float)).  It doesn't have to be a list of tuples, and specifying a dict of `{'names':['f0', 'f1' ...], 'formats':[np.float, np.int, ...]}` as a dtype is often a lot more convenient.

Comment: @Joe, Can 'f0', 'f1' be index? I typically have one col date or string, the rest are floats. Ex: 'foo', 1,2,2,44,3 or 22,2,2,2,2,'3/2/2001' whats the best dtype solutions?

Comment: +1 for noting the exceptions raised when the data input is different than a list of tuples, having bumped myself into this too often.